# Simple if conditional with goto triggers "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to do some basic checking of the first parameter in a Windows command script.  Let's call this foo.cmd (simplified contents shown below).  This script results in the error message "The syntax of the command is incorrect."  Turning `@echo on`, I can see the cause is any of the lines with `if` and `goto`.  If I replace the `goto :usage` with something like `echo bar` then the script works as I would expect.

```
@echo off

if "%~1"=="" goto :usage
if "%~1"=="/?" goto :usage
if "%~1"=="--help" goto :usage

goto :run

:usage
echo Usage: foo <parameter>
goto :eof

:run
echo Actual command will go here
goto :eof
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  I've looked at quite a few other questions and examples and this seems like it should work.

Comment: Don't write new batch files. Switch to PowerShell.

Comment: Ignore Bill Stewart, use batch exclusively.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree. PowerShell is superior to `cmd.exe` in nearly every conceivable way. For new users, PowerShell is a far better option than trying to learn all of the `cmd.exe` syntax quirks and oddities, many of which exist due for backward compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `echo Usage: foo <parameter>` line as `<` and `>` are redirection operators, and you tell the command interpreter to redirect the `echo` output to `>` nowhere. You need to escape them like `^<` and `^>`:

```
echo Usage: foo ^<parameter^>
```

To learn more about redirection and find some examples, follow [this external link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php).

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for the help!